# How to stop Matrix NSM TinyMCE field from converting HTML tags to entities

Tags: ee2, matrix, html-entities

I have a matrix with a text field and a NSM TinyMCE field. For some reason the NSM TinyMCE field keeps converting HTML tags to entities. So I get things like:

<p>&lt;p&gt;&amp;lt;p&amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;p&amp;amp;gt;&

Everytime I save the entry I get a new set of <p>&

I checked NSM TinyMCE field on its own and that works fine. No entities conversion.

I checked the channel for "Default HTML formatting in channel entries" and it's set to "Allow all HTML".

I also tried adding entity_encoding : "raw" in my TinyMCE config file.

My EE2 is v2.5.3 
Matrix 2.5.2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem please provide any guide...

Answer (score 1):

I saw this on another site that used a different CMS, it turned out to be an issue with magic_quotes on the server - we disabled magic-quotes and TinyMCE worked fine after that.

Comment: The magic quotes are already disabled on the server. Anything else I could try?

Comment: Turned off magic quotes and still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this by going to

`\system\expressionengine\third_party\nsm_tiny_mce\ft.nsm_tiny_mce.php`

```
return form_textarea(array(
   'name' => $this->cell_name,
   'id' => $this->col_id,
   'value' => $data,
   'rows' => ' ',
   'style' => "height: {$this->settings['height']}px"
  ));
```

**Replace this with**

```
return ' <textarea name="'.$this->cell_name.'" id="'.$this->col_id.'" style="height:'.$this->settings['height'].'px">'.$data.'< /textarea>';
```

Comment: Tried this - though needed to remove the space between the '<' and '/textarea>". Did not resolve the problem within the Matrix field, and made non-matrix fields have the HTML formatting.